# JAVA JSP include JSP and response too

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I would like to include an jsp and (separate) response with it too.

include:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><%@include file="content.jsp" %></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is content.jsp:

```
<p>${message}</p>
```

Message is a text from database. eg.: "Hello!"

Responses:
url: /

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

url: /hello

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

So my ask is how I recycle a jsp file if it is contain parameters?

Answer (score 0):

> So my ask is how I recycle a jsp file if it is contain parameters?

1. Using an efficient template system, fragmenting your jsp and create pages with single include.
2. Or you use

   ```
      <%  
         String message1 = request.getParameter("message");  
      %>

      <jsp:include page="...." >
         <jsp:param name="param1" value=<%=message1%> >
         </jsp:param>  
      </jsp:include>
   ```
3. Or you can copy and paste and using controller to manage the parameters.